# If we see someone in a spacecraft and their clock is running slower than ours do they see ours running even slower?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

From what I understand if we see someone's clock running slower than ours they will see ours running slower rather than theirs, but in my physics textbook they ask this question:

> A spacecraft zooms past the Earth with a constant velocity. An
>   observer on the Earth measures that an undamaged clock on the
>   spacecraft is ticking at one- third the rate of an identical clock on
>   the Earth. What does an observer on the spacecraft measure about the
>   Earth-based clock’s ticking rate?
>
> (a) It runs more than three times faster than his own clock.
>
> (b) It runs three times faster than his own.
>
> (c) It runs at the same rate as his own.
>
> (d) It runs at one-third the rate of his own.
>
> (e) It runs at less than one-third the rate of his own.

I thought the answer would be it runs one-third the rate of his own, but the correct answer (according to my book) is that it runs less than one-third the rate of his own. Is this correct? I don't know how to use the equations I've been given for special relativity to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understand if we see someone's clock running slower than ours they will see ours [...]

Determining and comparing (for clocks whose intications can be counted as "ticks") the ratios

$$ \frac{\hbox{Number } n \hbox{ of consecutive ticks of clock } A}{  \hbox{ Clock } A\hbox{'s Duration } \tau_{A} \hbox{ from the first one of these } n \hbox{ consecutive ticks until the final one}} $$

in order to find out whether

- any one clock ran/ticked at a constant rate, and
- whether two clocks, which were (separately) ticking at constant rates, had been ticking at equal rate(s), or which one had been running/ticking slower than the other

is not accomplished by merely one of them "*seeing*" the other;
but is a result of **measurement**.

> in my physics textbook they ask this question:
>
> A spacecraft zooms past the Earth with a constant velocity. An observer on the Earth measures

You see: **"*measures*"**!

> that an undamaged clock on the spacecraft is ticking at one- third the rate of an identical clock on the Earth.

Rubbish!
Clocks which were measured having run/ticked at unequal rates are certainly not called "*identical*"; and not even called "equal".

> What does an observer on the spacecraft measure about the Earth-based clock’s ticking rate? [...]

I strongly advise you, and especially your teacher, to get a better textbook that covers the topic of [special-relativity](/questions/tagged/special-relativity) **properly**.